# Add chat rooms for Android app

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app

Being able to join chat rooms from the Android app would be a plus! It would truly make us connected on the go, instead of having to sit down at our desks and open a browser window. *This will allow more users to fully utilize the chat system and join events no matter where they are.*

Comment: Oh yeah, more people using chat — *exactly* what Stack Overflow needs!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160597/150515

Comment: Just use a mobile browser and be done with. 3.5 years later, they just don't care.

Comment: Yeah, mobile site for the win here. So much better than the apps on all accounts aside from notifications. Still not quite sure why they don't just dump the apps entirely, replace them with a bare minimal inbox notification app, and focus on the superior, platform-independent mobile sites.

Comment: @MaskedMan: Although it's on the bandwidth-saving side, loading the full chat website for every room rather than just the minimum amount of data - i.e. the actual messages - still uses up unpleaseantly much data volume.

Comment: As the mobile apps are no longer supported I'm closing this as no longer reproducable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is possible, but very far down the roadmap -- definitely not in v1 of any of the mobile apps. It'd be a pretty big change for both chat and the app, and chat activity just doesn't seem to be large enough to justify it yet (I know, a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem).

In the meantime, the web version is actually pretty good and we use it internally a fair amount.

---

Update Jan 2016: This is still something we'd *like* to do some day, but it's not on the roadmap after 2 years, so pretty unlikely.

Comment: The web version is the best chat system I've used yet. Not that I've used many, but yeah.

Comment: Web chat is great. Web *mobile* chat on the other hand...

Comment: Chatting on a Nexus 10 for example is a bit pita. Zooming in/out makes divs overlapping each other and thus rendering the chat unusable.

Comment: No, mobile chat is not really useable. It lacks critical features

Comment: Since it's deferred and not declined, two and half years later, is there any chance it will ever be implemented?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes and no. Full mobile support for chat is unlikely, but we have some significant improvements to mobile web chat that we're testing internally and should be able to release to the community soonish.

Comment: I know about the mobile web @David, balpha mentioned it a while ago. But what about the android/iOS apps? If such thing is not planned I think it's better to mark this question and [its iOS equivalent](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226702/include-some-chat-capabilities-in-ios-app) as [tag:status-declined] so that people won't have false hopes. (And update the answer to reflect the reasons :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Mobile chat is something we'd *like* to do, but not on the roadmap right now.

Comment: Thanks, will ask again in 2 years or so.  :)

Comment: Why is this status-declined instead of status-deferred, then? If you read the descriptions for the tags, declined means you won't do it. Deferred means the suggestion has merit, but it's still a way off.

Comment: @Thomas David did explain it in the comment and edit: "something we'd like to do some day, but it's not on the roadmap" - hence not rejected which means "we don't want to do that, ever". Personally I still feel uncomfortable with the (lack of) decision, but now that it's explained better guess it's easier to live with.

Comment: "chat activity just doesn't seem to be large enough" - please be aware that on many SE sites, comment discussions that are relevant to questions/answers are routinely moved to chat by the mods. I rarely *post* anything in SE chatrooms (= generating activity?), but I regularly find myself entering a room just to read the migrated remarks from the comments.

Comment: Pretty much the same. On the SE site I’m most active on comment discussions are moved into chat all the time, but the lack of integration of chat on the apps means that I can’t participate most of the time.