# Adjusting hat position is damn near impossible on a tablet

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, winter-bash-2013, touch-screen

As the title says. I'm posting this using Chrome on an Android tablet, and it's next to impossible to adjust the Winter Bash hat position, since normal dragging doesn't work.

The only way I've found to make it work is to:

1. Click the hat and hold your finger down until the Chrome context menu pops up.
2. Dismiss the context menu by clicking somewhere else.
3. Click on or near the avatar, which (sometimes) causes the hat to teleport somewhere near the clicked spot.
4. If it didn't work, or if the hat didn't end up where you wanted, repeat until it does, or until you give up in frustration and just wear your hat on your nose / neck / left ear.

Obviously, I think this sucks. Can I haz bugfix plz?

Comment: I doubt the UI designers ever had touchscreens in mind..

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Probably not, but it's still unusable and should be fixed -- if not immediately, then at _least_ for next year. I can't be the only one using SO on a touch screen device, and they're not getting any _less_ common.

Comment: I can't move it with my tablet at all. It just offers to open my profile in a new tab or copy the link.

Comment: Not possible to perform a drag on my phone, at all. Luckily I can still use my computer, where I can use my mouse (and if I couldn't, I'd kill this drag to scroll feature).

Comment: The main website is not built to work on mobile devices. I doubt they're going to build in mobile support for Winterbash when they don't even have other, more important features for mobile devices. Simplest answer: it's not supported.

Comment: I (virtually exclusively) use an iPhone/Chrome to post. Never mind hats... chat is unusable on an iPhone. If you zoom in enough to read the text, the right nav panel flows across the whole screen. Clearly, no one in dev cares Chrome on iPhone :(

Comment: @Bohemian they work hard these days on app, for now there's one for android (invite only) and soon there will be one for iPhone as well. It supports all basic actions, but as for chat you better read [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191487) by the dev "team leader".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I considered adding touch support to the hat placement, but for this year I ran out of time. Note that hat switching is still possible, and that new hats (if possible) keep your previously chosen position; I've changed my hat on a tablet various times with the new hat ending up in the correct position. But if that doesn't place the hat in a satisfactory position, for now you're constrained to adjust it on a computer that has a mouse. For next year, this is definitely something I want to have.

Comment: OK, fair enough. What's kind of annoying about the current situation, though, is that if you _try_ to drag the hat on a touch screen, it's possible to accidentally move it to a random spot (basically by accidentally doing the steps I described above) with no obvious way to move it back. Actually, a "reset hat position" button would be kind of nice in general...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen maybe if you click "I hate hats" then "I love hats" again it will reset the position?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Nope, just tried it, didn't work... however, "take off your hat on this site" followed by "wear hat" does!

Comment: @IlmariKaronen oh well, so I fear only balpha can help by adding such an option.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen You can just close the hat rack popup. When you open it again, the hat is back in its original position.

Comment: Ah... yeah, that'd work. Honestly, I hadn't even thought about the fact that it doesn't autosave.