# Include some chat capabilities in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, chat, ios-app

Currently, the app notifies users when they're mentioned in chat. However, when we tap on the notification, we got redirected out of the app to Safari.

Is there a chance we can get some chat capabilities in the app, so that we don't have to login again in Safari to quickly reply to the messages?

[image]

App version: 0.1.19 09/19/2014

Comment: I can't believe this isn't up voted more. Chat is something that the web app does an atrocious job on iOS. Even getting logged in successfully is a bit of a challenge with how cookies and the site design works. I often can click links from the iOS app and get to safari properly logged in, but chat links almost always take me to the error message that you need 20 rep to chat...