# Add a link to chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, ios-app

I'm aware there's an [existing feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226702/233816) to add chat to the iOS app. As this doesn't appear to be coming in the very near future however, would it be possible to temporarily add a link to launch a site specific chat.stackexchange.com browser window?

Chat is relatively mobile friendly - just a bit of a bugger to get to...my current method is scrolling through all my notifications to find the last chat one, then going through that. (And then still having to scroll to the bottom and tap 'join this room'!) Hoping this is a 'labour-effective' solution to the problem, until chat is added natively.

Comment: Interesting technical challenge to the team: as it stands these days, the chat list of rooms is checking the HTTP referer to know what rooms to show you. When coming from the app, you won't have referer and you'll always see all rooms.

Comment: Thanks for the technical insight @ShadowWizard. That's an irritation, but still, a list of all rooms would be better than nothing...is there functionality to 'favourite' rooms? Or I presume there's a search at least, if nothing else!

Comment: Sure, each room has a star in the top right, and there is "favorite" tab in rooms list. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard can't they set the referer in the app?

Comment: @Scimonster hard to believe but I'm not iOS developer so who knows... :)

Comment: One can use http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=superuser.com which shows rooms for a site without the need for an HTTP referer (cc @Sha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now implemented, thanks!

[Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251507/233816)