# Stackoverflow chat in mobile app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, mobile-app

Is there a way to access a sites chat using the mobile app interface? I've been trying to figure it out because a swear I saw it before.

If not, where would one go to post such an idea to the developers of the app?

Comment: There is a FR for android already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191334/245360.

Comment: And here for iOS: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226702/245360

Answer (score 6):

You can, but it will redirect you to the site.

In the iOS app, click on the site name in the drop down. Then hit *More*. There is your option to *Open Chat*.

> [image]

Comment: Or alternatively, hold-press the site name in the menu bar - which will give a pop up to go to meta or chat.

Comment: @Chris didn't know that. Good suggestion.