# Where is the chat in mobile application?

Tags: support, chat, android-app

I am using the SE mobile app but not being able to find the chat... again (but this time the mobile app)

Comment: Which of the apps? iOS or android?

Comment: Anyway, there is no chat in any of the official apps. This is dupe of either [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226702/include-some-chat-capabilities-in-ios-app) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191334/add-chat-rooms-for-android-app), just say what app and I'll close. (Or you can remove the question if you prefer)

Comment: Let me reach a computer and I delete it. It is not useful as a dupe, i think. I asked it from the mobile device so could not search deeply

Comment: You can close it meanwhile as dupe.

Comment: OK, your call. Anyway, you got your answer, one way or another. :)

Comment: I can't close as duplicate, because you never told what app. I don't want to guess, making it wrong.

Comment: Android is my platform

Comment: Thank you for ur patience :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1006/discussion-between-shadow-wizard-and-luis-masuelli).