# Making chats usable inside the app

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app, ios-app

I've been recently talking with someone in the comments of my answer to his question on Stack Overflow, and he moved the discussion to the chat, for which I had to open my browser. Then I thought: **Why don't we have the ability to chat inside the Stack Exchange app?** Actually, not a bad thought, though.
I also noticed, the "create chat" privilege is not showing up in the app, but in the web interface it does.
Would like to see this added by the Developers.

Comment: This should be added on the iOS app too.

Comment: @angussidney Mh... Okay, I'll add the tag.

Comment: This would be nice but I'm guessing it would be very complicated.

Comment: @Catija Why would it be?

Comment: Because the way chat works is completely different to how the rest of the site works...

Comment: @Catija Yes, but they could first add the chats under posts (and notifications for them, perhaps?) and later the whole chat.stackoverflow.com. "Everything is complicated." said someone once.

Comment: ... My intention wasn't to say "don't hold your breath, they're never going to do this"... it was to say "this may take some time to be realized, so you may need to be patient."

Comment: @Catija See, I am using Stack Overflow. I'm a developer, and I know it takes time to develop things, especially when it comes to APIs and Android Apps.

Comment: Excuse me for not assuming everyone on SE is a developer.

Comment: This has been asked many times, in different variations. The official answer is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191487/152859) which in short is polite way to say "we will never do it". In all my years in SE, I have never seen [tag:status-deferred] becomes [tag:status-completed] - it's just another form of [tag:status-declined]